# error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'

Tags: angular

Делаю валидацию формы.
Код :

```
<div *ngIf="loginForm.get('name').invalid && 
  loginForm.get('name').touched" class="validation">
  <small> Поле "Название товара" не может быть пустым! 
  </small>
  <small> Введите корректное название! </small>
</div>

Возникает ошибка -  TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'. 
Чертит loginForm.get('name').invalid и 
loginForm.get('name').touched. Помогите разобраться что не 
так. 
Заранее спасибо!
```

Comment: Может вы добавите ещё код создание/использование формы? из всего вышеприведенного полезна только одна строка - `TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.`

Answer (score 0):

```
**app.component.html:**
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" 
(ngSubmit)="onSubmit(loginForm)">
<div>
  <label>Введите название товара:</label>
  <input type="text" formControlName='name'>
  <div *ngIf="loginForm.get('name').invalid && 
  loginForm.get('name').touched" 
  class="validation">
    <small> Поле "Название товара" не может 
  быть пустым! </small>
    <small> Введите корректное название! 
    </small>
  </div>
 </div>
 <input type="submit" 
 [disabled]="loginForm.invalid" class="btn 
btn-degault" value="Send">
  </form>

**app.component.ts:**
import { Component, OnInit } from 
'@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, FormGroup, FormControl, 
Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from 
'@angular/forms';
import { from } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
 
 public loginForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
"name" : new FormControl("", 
[Validators.required,Validators.minLength(4)])
  });

ngOnInit() {    
 }
 onSubmit(form: FormGroup) {
 }
}
```